# Changing my default primary GID for every login session

Tags: permissions, users

I read the following about [`newgrp`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/newgrp.1.html):

```
The newgrp command is used to change the current group ID during a
       login session.
```

This made me think, how can I change my default's primary group **permanently**?

I imagine I can have a `newgrp` line in my startup files for my shell, but is there a way to change my primary ID for every login session without resorting to `newgrp`?

I am interested in a generic solution, but in case it depends on the distribution, I am interested in solutions for **Ubuntu 11.10** and for **Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server** (I have administrator priviledges in the former, but not in the latter).

#### Addendum:

From the great answer @Shawn provided below to the these questions, I read "I won't be able to do this without root privileges".

This made me wonder: **why?** Assuming that I have privileges to run `newgrp` immiediately after login, wouldn't this be the same as changing my default primary GUID for all practical purposes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux (not BusyBox), Solaris, NetBSD, OpenBSD:
`usermod -g group`

> The usermod command modifies the system account files to reflect the changes that are specified on the command line
>
> **-g, --gid GROUP**
>
> The group name or number of the users new initial login group. The group must exist.
>   Any file from the users home directory owned by the previous primary group of the user
>   will be owned by this new group.
>
> The group ownership of files outside of the users home directory must be fixed manually.

On FreeBSD:
`pw usermod -g group`

On BusyBox:
`addgroup -g user group`

You won't be able to do this without root privileges.

Comment: +1 for nicely covering so many systems! Maybe you could also address the last (non-admin) part of the question?

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz As far as I know, adding `newgrp` to a startup script is the closest you can get without root privileges.

If you were the admin of such a system and you wanted to let your users switch between a subset of groups without giving them root privileges, you could write a program to let them do it, and set the `setuid` bit on the program.

Comment: I think so too. And this might be useful information to intrpc.