# modify group for one command

Tags: linux, bash, chgrp

I want to execute one command and I want that it is executed with a specific groupname, that I'm belonging to, but which is not my default group. So all files created will belong to that group.
Is there a command for that?

There is `chgrp` to fix it afterwards.

Then I found `newgrp` ([Changing my default primary GID for every login session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23093/changing-my-default-primary-gid-for-every-login-session)), but that creates a subshell. Thus a oneliner `newgroup <groupname> && cmd` does not work. And the shell needs to be closed later.

Both approaches looks error prone.

Comment: https://blog.famzah.net/tag/cap_setgid/

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208617/how-to-update-user-group-settings-of-a-running-process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `sg` can be used for this purpose.

Citing [`man sg`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sg.1.html)

```bash
sg [-] [group [-c ] command]
```

The `sg` command works similar to `newgrp` but accepts a command. The
command will be executed with the `/bin/sh` shell. With most shells you
may run `sg` from, you need to enclose multi-word commands in quotes.
Another difference between `newgrp` and `sg` is that some shells treat
`newgrp` specially, replacing themselves with a new instance of a shell
that `newgrp` creates. This doesn't happen with `sg`, so upon exit from a
`sg` command, you are returned to your previous group ID.

---

If you want to change the GID for multiple commands in a `bash` script, split the script in two and call the second script with `sg` or let the script call itself with `sg` and some arguments to avoid endless recursion.

In Python, there might be other ways to use the `setgit` system call.